# Refused to display iframe or embed tag in django 3.0 and chrome

Tags: django, iframe, embed, clickjacking

I had a django app that used an iframe to display a pdf stored in my local machine, something like this:

```
<embed src="path_to_file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

Everything worked just fine in all supported browsers... Until today.

The app suddenly stopped working on Chrome and the console displays the message **Refused to display 'path_to_file.pdf' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'**.

In other browsers it's still working as usual. I don't know if Chrome just made an update or what changed but it is not working anymore. ¡Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After going through a lot of similar questions and trying lots of different things, I finally found a solution for my problem thanks to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it).

> Since Django 3.0. The default value of the **X_FRAME_OPTIONS** setting was changed from **SAMEORIGIN** to **DENY**.

So I just had to add `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'` to settings.py and the problem was gone.

I still don't know what change made my code stop working because I already used django 3.0 version since it was released, probably it was a Chrome update.

Comment: Thanks, Manuel Montoya, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Recording an incident here specifically with a Vimeo embedded video. I needed to set `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY` to `None`. The default was changed in [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.1/#security).